# Display error message and return null in a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

How do I both display an error in the console and return a value in the second part of my iif, something like this:

```
return fetch(templatePath)
  .then((response) => response.ok ? response.text() : function() {
    console.error(`Template ${templatePath} not found.`);
    Promise.resolve(null);
  })
  .then((templateHtml) => {
    newElement.innerHTML = templateHtml;

    while (newElement.firstChild) {
      oldElement.appendChild(newElement.firstChild);
    }
  })
```

but this displays the function as a string instead of continuing with null like I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 error in the script:

1. the `function()` is an anonymous function, and it's not called, just declared, the
2. The anonymous function is not returning the declared promise `Promise.resolve(null);`

Solution:

```js
return fetch(templatePath)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) return response.text();
    console.error(`Template ${templatePath} not found.`);
    return null;
  })
  .then(...
```

Comment: Yep that's it I got it in the meantime ^^ thanks I'll validate your answer in 8 min, remind me !

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a function, just use a comma operator (`,`), that evaluates both operands, and returns the last:

```js
return fetch(templatePath)
  .then(
    (response) => response.ok ? response.text() : (console.error(`Template ${templatePath} not found.`), null)
  )
  .then((templateHtml) => {
    newElement.innerHTML = templateHtml;

    while (newElement.firstChild) {
      oldElement.appendChild(newElement.firstChild);
    }
  })
```

But it is recommended to reject the promise if an error happens instead:

```js
return fetch(templatePath)
  .then(
    (response) => response.ok ? response.text() : Promise.reject(new Error(`Template ${templatePath} not found.`))
  )
  .then((templateHtml) => {
    newElement.innerHTML = templateHtml;

    while (newElement.firstChild) {
      oldElement.appendChild(newElement.firstChild);
    }
  })
```

Comment: :o :o :o wow ok thanks! And why is null ok to return here? Don't I have to return a promise? Something like Promise.resolve(null)?

Comment: `.then` implicitly converts any non-thenable value into a resolved promise - just like `Promise.resolve()` does. So, you don't have to!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a function in case of an error, just return null.

Each `then` block returns a promise. When you return something that is not a promise, from a callback function passed to `then` function, the promise returned by the `then` function is resolved when the callback function returns and is immediately fulfilled with that non-promise value returned by the callback function.

In your case, in case of an error, promise returned by the first `then` function call will be fulfilled with the value of `null`.

If the return value of the callback function, passed to `then` function, is itself a promise, then the promise returned by `then` function call will be resolved but not yet settled. It will settle only when the promise returned by the callback function has settled.

In your case, if `response.ok` is true, callback function will return a promise `response.text`. The promise returned by `then` function call will be resolved but will settle only after this promise `response.text` has settled.

```
return fetch(templatePath)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) return response.text();

     console.error(`Template ${templatePath} not found.`);
     return null;
  })
  .then((templateHtml) => {
    newElement.innerHTML = templateHtml;

    while (newElement.firstChild) {
      oldElement.appendChild(newElement.firstChild);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
return fetch(templatePath)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.text();
    }
    else {
      console.error(`Template ${templatePath} not found.`);
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    }
  })
  .then((templateHtml) => {
    newElement.innerHTML = templateHtml;

    while (newElement.firstChild) {
      oldElement.appendChild(newElement.firstChild);
    }
  })
```